# how to install sql server cluster between two servers windows 2012 without external storage

Tags: sql-server-2012

Can anyone please help me on installing sql server 2012 on cluster mode between two servers running windows 2012 server without external storage?

I will use the sql for sharepoint 2013 installation for a file server so the need of fault tolerance is big.

Thanks everyone

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic and better be posted here http://dba.stackexchange.com/ instead

Comment: @MuhammadRaja In the advanced certification of Sharepoint 2013 ([70-332](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/exam-70-332.aspx)), 20% of the certification covers SQL Server, log shipping, clustering and mirroring. because of that I feel that this question could very well fit both on DBA.SE and here at SP.SE. No need to close this one as it stands.

Comment: @BennySkogberg thanks for letting me know, retracted my closing vote.

Comment: @MuhammadRaja You're welcome. Nice of you to retract the close vote. I didn't know that could be done. We both learn from each other :-)

Answer (score 3):

If we are talking SharePoint 2013 and SQL Server 2012 you have the possibility of creating an AlwaysOn cluster for high availability.

I recommend starting with [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sambetts/archive/2013/04/24/sharepoint-2013-and-sql-server-alwayson-high-availability-sharepoint.aspx) blog post that will give you a step-by-step guide on how to set it up. Then proceed to read all available articles on TechNet on the subject. This include [planning](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263420.aspx) (especially focus on [High Availability](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263031.aspx)), [install and configure](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj715261.aspx) & [operate and maintain.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc825329.aspx)

Read all the articles related to SQL before you start planning your approach, weather you need HA and what type of HA (AlwaysOn, Logshipping, Mirroring) and how you want to design your cluster.

Comment: @MuhammadRaja thanks for letting me know about the dba site, didn't about that.

Comment: but as this is a sharepoint forum and sql server is to run sp 13 so I thought could find help quicker, @AndersRask thanks for sharing the links, already reading them.

Comment: Definately some good help to be found in the DBA site also. Some stuff will be specific to SharePoint configuration-wize (eg. supported scenarios) but in general "good practices" for a fast performing SQL server (eg. RAID recommendations for tempdb, log files etc) works for a SharePoint farm as well.